# Issue with checkbox checked

Tags: java, android

i am use [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive) for setting checkbox in listview i have follow all step as per given tutorial, but there are some critical issue with output, is that when i am select first checkbox and scroll down it will change selected item and automatically appear 3rd.

so i think there are something wrong with getview. so please help me out this ....

here is my code ::

```
package com.AppFavorits;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;

public class Favorites extends ListActivity {
    protected static final String TAG = "Favorites";
    CommentsDataSource datasource;
    ListView lstFavrowlistv;
    ArrayList alAppName;
    float[] rate;
    boolean[] bSelected;
    ArrayList<Comment> alPackagenm;
    Drawable[] alIcon;
    ViewHolder holder;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        alAppName = datasource.getAllComments();
        alPackagenm = datasource.getAllPackage();

        Log.i(TAG, "values >>>" + alAppName);
        Log.i(TAG, "values >>>" + alPackagenm);
        int inc = 0;
        alIcon = new Drawable[200];
        for (int i = 0; i < alPackagenm.size(); i++) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Appname >>>" + GetAllApp.lstpinfo.get(i).pname);
            for (int j = 0; j < GetAllApp.lstpinfo.size(); j++) {
                if (alPackagenm
                        .get(i)
                        .toString()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                GetAllApp.lstpinfo.get(j).pname.toString())) {
                    alIcon[inc] = GetAllApp.lstpinfo.get(j).icon;
                    Log.i("TAG", "sqlPackagename"
                            + alPackagenm.get(i).toString());
                    Log.i("TAG", "from getAllapp"
                            + GetAllApp.lstpinfo.get(j).pname.toString());
                    inc++;
                }

            }
        }

        ArrayList<RowModel> list = new ArrayList<RowModel>();
        ArrayList<Model> Mlist = new ArrayList<Model>();
        rate = new float[alAppName.size()];
        bSelected = new boolean[alAppName.size()];
        Iterator itr = alAppName.iterator();
        String strVal = null;
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            strVal += itr.next().toString() + ",";

        }

        int lastIndex = strVal.lastIndexOf(",");
        strVal = strVal.substring(0, lastIndex);
        System.out.println("Output String is : " + strVal);
        String strAr[] = strVal.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < strAr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("strAr[" + i + "] " + strAr[i]);
        }

        for (String s : strAr) {
            list.add(new RowModel(s));
        }
        for (String s : strAr) {
            Mlist.add(new Model(s));
        }
        setListAdapter(new RatingAdapter(list, Mlist));
        datasource.close();
    }

    class RowModel {
        String label;
        float rating = 0.0f;

        RowModel(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        public String toString() {
            if (rating >= 3.0) {
                return (label.toUpperCase());
            }

            return (label);
        }
    }

    private RowModel getModel(int position) {
        return (((RatingAdapter) getListAdapter()).getItem(position));

    }

    class RatingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowModel> {
        private ArrayList<Model> mlist;

        RatingAdapter(ArrayList<RowModel> list, ArrayList<Model> mlist) {
            super(Favorites.this, R.layout.outbox_list_item,
                    R.id.txvxFavrowiconappname, list);
            this.mlist = mlist;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            if (holder == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder(row);
                row.setTag(holder);

                RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener l = new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,
                            float rating, boolean fromTouch) {
                        Integer myPosition = (Integer) ratingBar.getTag();
                        RowModel model = getModel(myPosition);

                        model.rating = rating;
                        rate[position] = rating;

                    }
                };
                holder.chkbxFavrowsel
                        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(
                                    CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                Model element = (Model) holder.chkbxFavrowsel
                                        .getTag();
                                element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                                bSelected[position] = isChecked;

                            }
                        });
                holder.chkbxFavrowsel.setTag(mlist.get(position));
                holder.ratingBar1.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(l);
            } else {
                row = convertView;
                ((ViewHolder) row.getTag()).chkbxFavrowsel.setTag(mlist
                        .get(position));
            }

            RowModel model = getModel(position);
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            holder.ratingBar1.setTag(new Integer(position));
            holder.ratingBar1.setRating(model.rating);
            holder.imgvFavrowiconappicon.setImageDrawable(alIcon[position]);
            holder.txvxFavrowiconappname.setText(alAppName.get(position)
                    .toString());
            holder.chkbxFavrowsel.setChecked(mlist.get(position).isSelected());

            return (row);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand your code exactly what you are trying to do. I haven't seen before this you are checking `holder == null` where as it should be `convertView == null`. If you have a scrolling issue you can check my [**blog post**](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)

```
 holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            if (holder == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder(row);
                row.setTag(holder);
               ...
            }
           else {
                row = convertView;
                ((ViewHolder) row.getTag()).chkbxFavrowsel.setTag(mlist
                        .get(position));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code to your MainActivity.java file.

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {

    ListView mLstView1;
    Button mBtn1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mLstView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mLstView1);
        String[] lv_items = { "Dipak", "Rahul", "Hiren", "Nandlal", "Keyur",
                "Kapil", "Dipak", "Rahul", "Hiren", "Nandlal", "Keyur",
                "Kapil" };
        ;
        mLstView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, lv_items));
        mLstView1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        mBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtn1);
        mBtn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Using a List to hold the IDs, but could use an array.
                List<Integer> checkedIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                // Get all of the items that have been clicked - either on or
                // off
                final SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = mLstView1
                        .getCheckedItemPositions();
                for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.size(); i++) {
                    // And this tells us the item status at the above position
                    final boolean isChecked = checkedItems.valueAt(i);
                    if (isChecked) {
                        // This tells us the item position we are looking at
                        final int position = checkedItems.keyAt(i);
                        // Put the value of the id in our list
                        checkedIDs.add(position);
                        System.out.println("Position is:- " + position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```